# Something strange about TEXTMETRIC

Tags: windows, winapi

I am reading

> Programming.Windows.5th.Edition,Charles Petzold

when I was doing the Figure 4-5. SYSMETS1.C,I met the following codes:

```
cxCaps = (tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1 ? 3 : 2) * cxChar / 2 ;
```

and there are explanations in the book,

> SYSMETS1 also saves an average width of uppercase letters in the static variable cxCaps. For a fixed-pitch font, cxCaps would equal cxChar. For a variable-width font, cxCaps is set to 150 percent of cxChar. The low bit of the tmPitchAndFamily field in the TEXTMETRIC structure is 1 for a variable-width font and 0 for a fixed-pitch font. SYSMETS1 uses this bit to calculate cxCaps from cxChar.

Now that cxCaps is set to 150 percent of cxChar,I think it should be

cxCaps = (tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1 ? **3.0** : **2.0**) * cxChar / 2 ;

Can you explain it for me?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to calculate an *integer* result, expressed in pixels.  The effective calculation is `(3 * cxChar) / 2`, not `3 * (cxChar / 2)`.  Presumably the latter one is giving you pause.

It's going to get rounded down for a proportional font but will never be off by more than a single pixel.  It doesn't matter since the value is only a guess anyway, the actual width is different for every glyph in a proportional font.

No points scored for readability, you could perhaps rewrite it like this:

```
bool proportional = tm.tmPitchAndFamily & TMPF_FIXED_PITCH;
if (proportional) cxCaps = (3 * cxChar) / 2;
else cxCaps = cxChar;
```

Note how the flag has the wrong name, perhaps the reason Petzold wrote it like that.

Comment: I like how the MSDN documentation has "Note very carefully that those meanings are the opposite of what the constant name implies."

Comment: Microsoft often make such funny things

Answer (score 2):

What are the types of `cxChar` and `cxCaps`? If `cxChar` is `float` or `double`, then there is no problem, because the result of the multiplication will be converted to that type before dividing by 2, and the result would be 1.0 or 1.5. But `cxCaps` should also be of a floating point type, so it can hold the floating point value.

**EDIT**

I checked to code of the book, and found that they are both `int`. And also I found that there is no need for floating point variables.
For example assume that `cxCahr` is 20. If `tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1` results in `1`, then the expression will be

```
cxCaps = 3 * cxChar / 2;
```

and `cxCaps` will be `30`. And if the result is 0, 'cxCaps' will be '20'. So everything is fine. If cxChar is an odd number, then the lost value will be `0.5`, that could easily be neglected.

Comment: Frankly speaking,the reason for asking this question is just because I don't know the types of cxChar and cxCaps,I try to find it ,maybe the type is BYTE,namely unsigned char.